# Incorrect overflow on pseudo elements in IE11 and below

Tags: css, internet-explorer, overflow

I'm having trouble getting IE11 and below (as well as Safari 5.1 on Windows) to properly apply overflow: hidden to pseudo elements with a border radius.

Adding overflow: hidden to the parent element solves the problem but unfortunately in my case I can't apply overflow hidden to the parent.

```
div:after {
  content: "X";
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 300px;  
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here's a pen to illustrate:

http://codepen.io/alexandtheweb/pen/GgMyXO

Comment: Have you tried adding a relative position to the parent element?

Comment: @HeriHeheSetiawan I did, with no luck. Also tried text-overflow: clip and adding position: relative to the pseudo element itself.

Comment: @AlexG Can you modify your html structure at all?

Comment: @Ursus I may have to. Adding an inner element with overflow: hidden and appending the pseudo element to that would work.

Comment: @AlexG I would do that.